# Reordering Sequences in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a sequence with the following data order:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O
```

and I need to sort it so that it looks like this:

```
A, F, K, B, G, L, C, H, M, D, I, N, E, J, O
```

which is basically grouping the first sequence in to three groups, stacking them on the top of each other and reading down the first column and then the next etc to form the new sequence.

```
ABCDE

FGHIJ

KLMNO
```

I have a conceptual understanding that this might involve mapping and zipping. I could implement this in short order in imperative style, but I want it as a functional style.

Any help/pointers gratefully received, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
val xs = Seq('A, 'B, 'C, 'D, 'E, 'F, 'G, 'H, 'I, 'J, 'K, 'L, 'M, 'N, 'O)
val grouped = xs.grouped(5).toList
// List(List('A, 'B, 'C, 'D, 'E), List('F, 'G, 'H, 'I, 'J), List('K, 'L, 'M, 'N, 'O))
val result = grouped.transpose.flatten
// List('A, 'F, 'K, 'B, 'G, 'L, 'C, 'H, 'M, 'D, 'I, 'N, 'E, 'J, 'O)
```

Comment: Thanks, does transpose only work on rectangular matrix? What if the input seq was only up to 'M' so the group function produced three lists of sizes 5-5-3 ?

Comment: `.transpose` raises an exception if the collections do not all have the same length (you might want to look up `.padTo` if this can happen).

Comment: @user3231690 then it will bail out `IllegalArgumentException`. Is this a problem for you?

Comment: yes, this potentially is a problem. I was going to make sure that they were same length by checking and then padding. Does .padTo do this?

Comment: @user3231690 yes, you can use `.padTo` to pad very last group (or initial sequence) with the dummy values. I will try to come up with the more robust solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Any solution should start out with `grouped`, which chops the collection into pieces:

```
scala> val g = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN".grouped(5)
g: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator   // Will return "ABCDE", then "FGHIJ", then "KLMN"
```

We then turn everything into a list so we can take tails easily:

```
scala> val l = g.map(_.toList).toList
List[List[Char]] = List(List(A, B, C, D, E), List(F, G, H, I, J),
                        List(K, L, M, N))
```

Now we gather these by taking successive tails, stopping when there's nothing left:

```
scala> val i = Iterator.iterate(l)(_.map(_ drop 1).filter(_.nonEmpty)).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
i: Iterator[List[List[Char]]] = non-empty iterator
// List(List(A, B, C, D, E), List(F, G, H, I, J), List(K, L, M, N))
// List(List(B, C, D, E), List(G, H, I, J), List(L, M, N))
// List(List(C, D, E), List(H, I, J), List(M, N))
// List(List(D, E), List(I, J), List(N))
// List(List(E), List(J))
```

That looks big, but since we're using a `List`, the shorter lists share memory with the longer ones, so it's not a horrible O(n^2) explosion in size.  But we really just want the heads, and we already filtered out everything empty, so we can just do it:

```
scala> val h = i.map(_.map(_.head))
h: Iterator[List[Char]] = non-empty iterator
// List(A, F, K)
// List(B, G, L)
// List(C, H, M)
// List(D, I, N)
// List(E, J)
```

and finally convert from an iterator to a strict collection and flatten:

```
scala> val ans = h.toList.flatten
ans: List[Char] = List(A, F, K, B, G, L, C, H, M, D, I, N, E, J)
```

(add `mkString` if you want a `String` back).

Note that the temporary variables are for clarity of explanation only.  If you feel like writing it all on one line, you could.  (It'd be a rather long line.)

(Also note that if you e.g. print out iterators, they get consumed.)

Here it is in one big swoop:

```
("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN".grouped(5).map(_.toList).toList match {
  case l => Iterator.iterate(l)(_.map(_ drop 1).filter(_.nonEmpty)).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
 }).map(_.map(_.head)).toList.flatten
```

but that's pretty opaque, so spreading things out to give room for comments is a good idea.